# How to obtain the latest record using PARTITION BY in a performant way in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, query-performance, sqlperformance

In our normalized Oracle 12.2 database used for obtaining information for dashboards and reports we have found that users often come across a need of wanting to know the data on the most recent record per some partition. In some cases we can filter the data to a smaller subset, whereas in others the whole data set is desired. In most cases users want to know the latest results for multiple partitions at once. The typical pattern for this is in oracle is as follows:

```
select * from (
    select my_table.*,
           row_number() over (partition by fk1, fk2, ... order by my_date desc) rn
    from my_table
    [where fk1 = 1234]
) where rn = 1
```

Originally we wanted to abstract this out into a view for convenience so people could just write a query against a view. We tried something like this:

```
create view my_table_latest as (
    select * from (
        select my_table.*,
               row_number() over (partition by fk1, fk2, ... order by my_date desc) rn
        from my_table
    ) where rn = 1
)

select * from my_table_latest where fk1 = 1234
```

Unfortunately this had two problems. First, it seems that the analytical function inside of the view always computes over the entire table before applying any filters. Hence the full table was scanned regardless of the filters and indexes that were used. Second, when used on tables with millions of records the queries were taking longer than we would like.

Given that we would like our data to stay relatively fresh (within 10 minutes), what would be the best way to obtain the latest records for some business key in a performant manner? The method to obtain the data should be hidden in a view so it is easily consumable by the fronting dashboarding application.

Here are two ideas that we had:

- **Materialized View** - Use a materialized view to recompute the results every 10 minutes. Given that the query takes several minutes to compute we are concerned this may not work well. Furthermore, based on what we found with having the analytical query in a view we suspect that using a more efficient refresh strategy would not work due to the use of the analytical function.
- **Track as we go** - Given that we have access to the code that writes the data and data is always processed oldest -> newest we could easily keep track of the latest record and save it off to a different table. A view then could be created that uses this information and joins back to the original table to obtain the rest of the record details. The "custom index" table would be something like (fk1, fk2, my_table.pk, date). Unfortunately this would require a code change.

Comment: "People could just write a query"? Your users write queries themselves?

Comment: On a sidenote: It's much work to sort all records in order to give them row numbers only to pick the first one. It's much less work to simply find the maximum date (`max(my_date) over (...)`) and compare it with the records' dates. (But, well, maybe the optimizer does this internally anyway.)

Comment: The database is fronted by a UI with a user friendly query builder. The option to write raw SQL is available.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it faster to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.my_date = (select max(t2.my_date)
                   from my_table t2
                   where t2.fk1 = t.fk1 and t2.fk2 = t.fk2 and . . .
                  );
```

Oracle may find it easier to optimize this when using a view with filtering in the outer query.  For performance, you want an index on `(fk1, fk2, . . ., my_date)`.

This assumes that the date is not repeated for a given combination of keys.

Comment: Couldn't this result in duplicate rows if two happened to share the same date?

Comment: @MarkRx . . . That is easily addressed if your table has a primary key.

Comment: What I mean is I would only want to see a single record if multiple records in the same key combintation have the same date.

Comment: I suppose I could follow the same pattern to have a tie-breaker by pk for a little more computation.

Comment: @MarkRx . . . You would use `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: We want to be able to retrieve multiple FK combinations at once. For example, find the latest set of records for (fk1, fk2) filtering on fk2. I could be missing something here but I don't see how to use fetch first in this case.

Comment: We ended up using correlated subqueries in some cases while building special tables to track the latest value in others. To handle the possibility of two records having the same date we used another correlated subquery using the max of the PK as the tie breaker.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of brainstorming:

1. Create a SQL `TYPE` representing your row type; read [Oracle docs for further details](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm)

```
create type my_table_t as( /* same fields as my_table */ );
```

2. Create a `PIPELINED` function that receives all the parameters you need and returns the rowtype you need. Read [Oracle documentation about pipelined table functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm) for further details. In its most generic form, you would receive a `varchar2` containing a user-provided SQL filter, but as that can be vulnerable to injection attacks I suggest using other alternatives, such as accepting (fk1, ..., fkn) as parameters. Let's call this function `query_my_table`. Inside this query, you *dynamically* generate the exact SQL you need, open a `REF CURSOR` and `PIPE` every row. As you are generating a specific SQL for each case, you can issue the exact query you need and do not need to rely in view behaviour.

```
create or replace function query_my_table(fk1 number, ..., fkn number) return my_table_t pipelined is
    query varchar2;
begin
   query := /* Create a string with the exact SQL you need */
   /* open ref cursor for query using fk1, ..., fkn */
   loop
       /* fetch & exit when not_found */
       /* load data into instance of my_table_t */
       pipe row(my_table_t_instance);
    end loop;
    /* close ref cursor */
    return;
end issue
```

3. You can then `SELECT` that by issuing:

   `select * from table(query_my_table(fk1, ..., fkn));`

This is just another application of the same features used by`dbms_xplan.display`. The main problem I can think of with this approach is that it does not compose very well: as Oracle has no statistics about the `table(...)` bit, if you start joining that with other tables, the optimizer is not going to be able to optimize that much. But if it is kind of "the final query", it should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query and implement this as views:

```
select *
  from my_table
 where ROWID IN (SELECT first_value(ROWID) over (PARTITION BY fk1, fk2, ...
                                                     ORDER BY my_date DESC)
                   FROM my_table)
```

Index on the fk1,fk2,...,my_date could be helping to speed the query.

Comment: We want to be able to see multiple fk combinations at once. For example, find the latest records with (fk1, fk2) combo where fk1 = some value.

Comment: I reworked my query to fit your conditions - missunderstood the question a bit...

Comment: Unfortunately by using the first_value analytical function it can't go in a view as it results in full table scans. The filter does not get applied until the function is computed over the entire table.